# «Тёмная ночь». Пунктуация. НЕ или НИ?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие, не-или-ни, поэзия

Вопрос навеян прошедшим (но никогда не забываемым!) праздником.

> Темная ночь, только пули свистят по степи,
>   Только ветер гудит в проводах, тускло звезды мерцают.
>   В темную ночь ты, любимая, знаю, не спишь,(1)
>   И у детской кроватки тайком ты слезу утираешь.
>
> Как я люблю глубину твоих ласковых глаз,
>   Как я хочу к ним прижаться сейчас губами!
>   Темная ночь разделяет, любимая, нас,
>   И тревожная,(2) черная степь пролегла между нами.
>
> Верю в тебя, в дорогую подругу мою,
>   Эта вера от пули меня темной ночью хранила...
>   Радостно мне, я спокоен в смертельном бою,(3)
>   Знаю(4) встретишь с любовью меня, что б со мной **ни** случилось.
>
> Смерть не страшна, с ней не раз мы встречались в степи.
>   Вот и сейчас надо мною она кружится.
>   Ты меня ждешь и у детской кроватки не спишь,
>   И поэтому(5) знаю:(6) со мной ничего не случится!
>   [Владимир Агатов](http://www.9maya.ru/2009/07/02/temnaya-noch-istoriya-sozdaniya-pesni.html) (Википедия)

1. Нужны или нет **(1)** и **(2)** запятые?
2. В некоторых текстах на месте **(3)** запятой стоит двоеточие.
3. Запятая **(4)** пропущена ошибочно или нужен другой знак?
4. На отметках **(5)** и **(6)** иногда стоят запятые.
   (*И поэтому, знаю, со мной ничего не случится.*)
5. Во всех текстах — *что б со мной **ни** случилось.* (Я бы написала **не**.)

Скажите, а как бы вы "оформили" это известное стихотворение?

[Во избежание поисков: [текст 1](https://text-master.ru/songs/temnaja-noch.html); [текст 2](http://drinking-songs.ru/slova-pesen/tyomnaya-noch.html); [текст 3](https://unotices.com/page-text.php?id=28830); [текст 4](https://libverse.ru/agatov/tiomnaya-noch.html); [текст 5](https://www.kino-teatr.ru/kino/movie/sov/1619/song/print/).]

Answer (score 2):

Моё видение таково:

*В темную ночь ты, любимая, знаю, не спишь,*(1)
*И у детской кроватки тайком ты слезу утираешь*.
Предложение сложносочинённое (ты не спишь, и ты  слезу утираешь ). Запятая нужна.

*Темная ночь разделяет, любимая, нас,*
*И тревожная,(2) черная степь пролегла между нами.*
Данные определения в основном значении неоднородные, можно запятую не ставить, но чёрный цвет вызывает тревогу, возможно увидеть и однородность определений по качеству отрицательных эмоций, поэтому запятая тоже корректна, прибавляет эмоций.

*Радостно мне, я спокоен в смертельном бою,*(3)
*Знаю(4) встретишь с любовью меня, что б со мной ни случилось*.
Безусловно, какой-то знак после "знаю" необходим: или запятая, или двоеточие. Под цифрой (3) тоже может быть двоеточие или запятая. Возможны варианты:

1. *Радостно мне, я спокоен в смертельном бою,(3)*
   *Знаю,(4) встретишь с любовью меня, что б со мной ни случилось*.
2. *Радостно мне, я спокоен в смертельном бою:(3)*
   *Знаю,(4) встретишь с любовью меня, что б со мной ни случилось*.
3. *Радостно мне, я спокоен в смертельном бою,(3)*
   *Знаю:(4) встретишь с любовью меня, что б со мной ни случилось*.

**Что ни** — верно, это уступительный союз, как и **где ни, куда ни, когда ни**, присоединяет придаточное уступительное. Здесь нет отрицания, частица в союзе усилительная.

*И поэтому(5) знаю:(6) со мной ничего не случится!* — бессоюзное сложное предложение, вторая часть раскрывает содержание первой.

*И поэтому,(5) знаю,(6) со мной ничего не случится!* — запятые отделяют вводное слово.

Answer (score 1):

(Пришлось создать новый аккаунт из-за блока старого. Это всё тот же я.)

Темная ночь, только пули свистят по степи,
Только ветер гудит в проводах, тускло звезды мерцают.
В темную ночь ты, любимая, знаю, не спишь

//В данном случае запятая не нужна (два однородных сказуемых, соединенных одиночным союзом "и")

И у детской кроватки тайком ты слезу утираешь.

Как я люблю глубину твоих ласковых глаз,
Как я хочу к ним прижаться сейчас губами!
Темная ночь разделяет, любимая, нас,
И тревожная, черная степь пролегла между нами.

//В данном случае обособление зависит от смысловой нагрузки. Если автор хотел создать образ степи, жуткой и пугающей, то слово "чёрная" будет считаться однородным по отношению к эпитету "тревожная", следовательно обособление будет. В случае прямого смысла признаки будут считаться неоднородными, поэтому обособления не будет.

Верю в тебя, в дорогую подругу мою,
Эта вера от пули меня темной ночью хранила...
Радостно мне, я спокоен в смертельном бою,

//Здесь действительно может стоять двоеточие, подразумевающее бессоюзную связь между двумя частями предложения, где одно является пояснением первого. Ставить запятую или двоеточие — решать Вам.

Знаю: встретишь с любовью меня, что б со мной ни случилось.

//Как Вы выразилась, здесь ошибка присутствует точно, т.к. отсутствие знака является ошибкой. Другой вопрос — выбор между тире, двоеточием и запятой. По смыслу я бы выбрал двоеточие.

Смерть не страшна, с ней не раз мы встречались в степи.
Вот и сейчас надо мною она кружится.
Ты меня ждешь и у детской кроватки не спишь,
И поэтому(,) знаю(,) : со мной ничего не случится!

//Запятые могут ставиться на основании вводного слова, обозначающего связь мыслей в предложении. Опять же, ПОЛНОСТЬЮ зависит от смысла.

Ответ на вопрос #5:
Здесь "ни" необходима чисто для выразительности. Фактически данную частицу можно опустить, не потеряв смысл (с "не" такого сделать нельзя)

Comment: *Ответ на вопрос #5: Здесь "ни" необходима чисто для выразительности. Фактически данную частицу можно опустить, не потеряв смысл (с "не" такого сделать нельзя)* Ну, опустите. **Что б со мной случилось.** И как?

Comment: Я не это имел в виду. Если Вы не знаете элементарных вещей, использующихся для проверки написания того или иного члена, я не виноват.

Comment: Что вы имели в виду, никому не известно. Но написали ерунду.

Answer (score 1):

> > Нужны или нет (1) и (2) запятые?

(1) - можно обосновать вариант без запятой, но он крайне надуман. Для этого надо признать "знаю" вводным и тогда две части сложносочиненного предложения будут иметь общую часть. Но куда все-таки естественнее считать "знаю, не спишь" сокращением "знаю, что не спишь" - и таким образом мотивировать запятую необходимостью обособления "(что) не спишь"

(2) - полностью на волю автора. Я не рассматриваю эти члены как неоднородные. Все известные мне исполнители (начиная с Бернеса) со мной согласны, там явная пауза как при перечислении.

> В некоторых текстах на месте (3) запятой стоит двоеточие.

Можно, но тоже не очень естественно. Здесь нет явного раскрытия смысла предыдущего, опять-таки ближе к перечислению.

> ```
> Запятая (4) пропущена ошибочно или нужен другой знак?
> ```

Какой-то знак нужен однозначно, мне ближе запятая. Но не будум спорить с двоеточием.

> На отметках (5) и (6) иногда стоят запятые.
>       (И поэтому, знаю, со мной ничего не случится.)

Идея понятна. "Знаю" рассматривается как вводное. Но мне такой вариант здесь не нравится. Я бы просто заменил двоеточие на запятую - для единообразия похода хотя бы. Ну не люблю я таких неочевидных двоеточий...

> Во всех текстах — что б со мной ни случилось. (Я бы написала не.)

Ну это вы что-то недодумали. ))) Здесь же нет отрицания как такового. Ни - здесь усилительная частица.

Короче, по сравнению с каноническим текстом я на месте автора внес бы только одну правку - двоеточие (6) заменил на запятую. Но это тот случай, когда автору виднее.

Answer (score 0):

Ну как же... *Что бы ни случилось. Где бы я ни был. Как бы он ни старался.* И так далее. Везде НИ.

(Но! Знаете такой слоган – кажется, какой-то страховой компании: **Чтобы не случилось.** Блестяще!)

В (1) запятой нет, в (2) оба варианта допустимы, в (3) может быть и двоеточие, в (4) запятая, в (5) никакого знака, в (6) оба варианта верны. Вроде все просто.